# XCTest case unable to access navigation controller

Tags: ios, unit-testing, singleton

I'm running unit tests in application test mode for UI automation testing in XCode. My application loads and sets up its navigation controller as a singleton, and whenever the main application makes a call to [navigationManager sharedInstance], it returns the singleton. However, in my XCTest, when I try to access [navigationManager sharedInstance], it returns nil. Does anyone know why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: **doesn't use sharedInstance when you are writing Unit Test**

In your `navigationManager` class, you have an `init` method, so in your `unit test`, create an instance with init, and use that to test.

*Shared Instance* are not good in testing, this is the reason because would be better use `Dependency Injection`, so initialize an object and pass it to every other object that you wish use it.

For example i initialize my `DataManager` in `AppDelegate` and then pass the `dataManager` to my `rootViewController`. If i open another controller i pass the `dataManager` to it, etc. 
This is the best architecture also to test  because in your test you can also create a `MOCK` of `DataManager` and use that to pass it to the `viewController` and test something else.

Comment: It's a singleton that's always created by every app that uses a navigation controller. It's what a navigation controller IS. It's part of how Apple set up iOS. I can't just not use it, or I would.

Comment: I just explain what is the point, if you don't trust me, search on google and you will find what i say above. You can also use it, but you have to not use the sharedInstance but use the init access..do you use `dispatch_once` in your init? that is a problem in share instance testing for example..

Comment: It's an Apple singleton. I can't see the source code. I did, however, solve the problem. If you import the singleton class in your build target, it will reset them between launching the app and running the tests.